# forEach objects value equals undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object, firebase-realtime-database

Data Received from `firebase-realtime-database` as following

```json
{
  "0": {
    "id": 10250903,
    ...
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 10810490,
    ...
  },
    ...
}
```

Code to `setProducts`

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState();
  const {isLoading, setIsLoading} = useData();
  useEffect(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref('events')
      .once('value')
      .then((events) => {
        setProducts(events);
      })
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

I tried to iterate the object to get the values

```js
products?.forEach((product) => {
              console.log(product);
});
```

Result:

```json
Object {
  "id": 10250903,
  ...
}
Object {
  "id": 10810490,
  ...
}
```

But when I try to access `id` values, console prints undefined

```js
products?.forEach((product) => {
              console.log(product.id); // undefined
});
```

```js
undefined
undefined
```

I am stuck I tried everything.

- `Object.values(products)` will not work since product will be undefined until data is received.
- Creating a new Array and mapping into it also will not work.

Comment: You've shown the working code, but not the code that fails?

Comment: @Bergi I edited the question and added the failing part

Comment: `product` is an array *or* an object?

Comment: You can not use forEach on objects, please post correct data structure.

Comment: You can use forEach on a Map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) or a list (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and in the former case, the function argument takes up to 3 args `value`, `key`, `map`. Does JavaScript have a `?.` operator now or are you using a different language?

Comment: @Jerry101 that's optional chaining, it is part of JS language only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that:

> Object.values(products) will not work since product will be undefined until data is received.

I think you are very close to the solution.
Using `products || {}` handles the case where `products` are `undefined` or `null`.

```
var products = {
  "0": {
    "id": 10250903,
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 10810490,
  },

}
Object.values(products || {}).forEach(p => console.log(p.id))
```

If you are transforming products into a new products collection, `reduce` *may* become useful:

```
Object.values(products || {}).reduce((acc, p) => { 
  acc[p.id] = p; 
  return acc; 
}, {})
```

=>

```json
{
  "10250903": {
    "id": 10250903,
    ...
  },
  "10810490": {
    "id": 10810490,
    ...
  }
}
```

Or:

```
Object.values(products || {}).reduce((acc, p) => { 
  acc.push(p.id)
  return acc; 
}, [])
```

=>
`[10250903, 10810490]`

Comment: It didn't work </3

Comment: If you can provide a little more detail, I think we will be able to overcome this problem. There are a number of ways to help clarify the problem. One is to enter your code into a Codepen https://codepen.io/pen/. If the type of the input object `product` is clearer, then the answer will be easier. Can you execute `console.log(JSON.stringify(product, null, 2))`?

Comment: I just edited the post and share the whole process.

Comment: Seeing the structure of `events`, running `console.log(JSON.stringify(events, null, 2))` might help too. Are you able to try that?

Comment: It did help with printing and that what I was looking for as a print but I am trying to get the values to set it to the views, so I am not quite sure how to acheive this, this was killing me last night until now...

Comment: I tried to use an array and push `JSON.stringify(products, null, 2)` with no luck, I tried to use an Object and assign `JSON.stringify(products, null, 2)` and received a brand new error, `PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`. I am out of ideas.

Comment: That is unfortunate. You have run into the maximum limit of a string. It is useful information. Because of the large size of data, it tells me there could unknown variation. You could start with a small sample size, for example just use the last two products `Object.values(products || {}).slice(-2)`

Comment: finally I solved this issue. Thanks to you. I used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product, null, 2));` to parse objects to a json then access the values. Thank you for helping me out. <3